# How to Inject vue router to an existing vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application, vue-router

I need router only for checkout page, checkout component is loaded asynchronously.

***components.js***

```
const VueComponents = [
......
{ name: 'cart-page', constructor: () => import(/*webpackChunkName: 'checkoutAndAccount'*/ './cartPage/cartPage') },
......
];
```

***app.js***

```
.....
    import { VueComponents } from './components/components';
.....
    if (VueComponents) {
      const componentsToRegister = VueComponents.filter(vueComponent => !!document.querySelectorAll(`${vueComponent.name}, [is="${vueComponent.name}"]`).length);

      for (const vueComponent of componentsToRegister) {
        Vue.component(vueComponent.name, vueComponent.constructor);
      }
    }

    this.vueInstance = new Vue({
      el: this.rootElement
    });
.....
```

I ***Don't*** want to do this :

```
    this.vueInstance = new Vue({
      el: this.rootElement,
      router
    });
```

I need to add router to the vue instance only on "cart-page" component, so something like :

***cartPage.vue***

```
name: 'cart-page',
beforeCreate() {
vueInstance.extends(router);
}
```

1. How do I access vue instance?
2. How do I add router to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Rooter is meant to be a global component, requests generally go through a router pretty early. Is there a reason why you only want to use it for one component ?

Comment: please check this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1117